# The final policy size (20539) is bigger than the limit (20480)

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda function, I am creating triggers for aws lambda function, I created 54 triggers using rules , I have to create more triggers but when I am adding 1 more triggers , I am getting this error message `The final policy size (20539) is bigger than the limit (20480)`.

How can I increase policy size?

Policy size means the size of the json ?

Comment: Can you specify what type of rules you are trying to add as triggers to your lambda function and also why so many individual rules are needed for a single lambda function. Probably the `maximum allowed size of resource based policies for lambda is 20480 bytes` and you have hit the maximum. See if you can combine the rules to minimize the number of triggers.

Comment: My Lambda function is a Java class, I have to run this java class with different set of arguments, the combination of arguments are different and more, I cant combine them

Comment: Any update here? Did you figure anything out?

Comment: Wow, 54 different triggers? You really can't consolidate and parameterize them? Are you using SAM template, serverless? How are you creating the triggers?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. You can see the relevant file (that its size exceeded) by opening the lambda console and then navigate to Permissions tab. The Function Policy in the image below is the limited file.

[image]

According to AWS support, you can't increase the limit. They suggest to delete the permission per rule and add permission when the `SourceArn` has a wildcard, for example `'arn:aws:events:{region}:{account}:rule/*'`. You can make the expression something more specific according to your needs.

That solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Now you need to check your lambda resources based policy if there are some unwanted Resources, remove it else you can use wildcard Resources for some resources. You can do that only from CLI. That's the way for resolve the issue.

Below commands for remove and add resources:

```
aws lambda remove-permission  --function-name  <function name> --statement-id <sid>

aws lambda add-permission --function-name <function name> --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id <sid> --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com --source-arn <Source arn>
```