# Adding many cloudwatch logs triggers to a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have many cloudwatch log groups (more than 50). I created a lambda function that monitors cloudwatch logs for issues I defined and tested it on a single group. The lambda itself works, and I'd like to set all my log groups as triggers for the lambda function.

After setting about 40, I got

> An error occurred when creating the trigger: The final policy size
>   (20839) is bigger than the limit (20480). (Service: AWSLambda; Status
>   Code: 400; Error Code: PolicyLengthExceededException;

Alright, reading about it here: [The final policy size (20539) is bigger than the limit (20480)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603701/the-final-policy-size-20539-is-bigger-than-the-limit-20480) and here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html , I understood I should manually change the permission policy. I deleted the existing permissions for about 4 triggers, then added a permission:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name=FUNCNAME --region=us-west-2 --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id genericpermission --principal logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com --source-account ACCOUNT  --source-arn arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:ACCOUNT:log-group:*
```

At this point, the list of triggers of my lambda was emptied. (although the subscriptions still exist.)

Question:
Is there a "right" way to have a lot of triggers, while still being able to review the triggers in the UI?

Comment: Sorry, cannot you add a cloudwatch alarm that will monitor the logs for issues (based on a pattern in your logs) and triggers your lambda only when such an issue happens? This way you will have only one trigger (cloudwatch alarm) but still able to monitor all log groups.